# Linear Layouts inside Linear Layout - recursively adding linear layouts depending on object

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

**EDIT SKIP TO BELOW**

I am trying to make a reddit app for android, the only problem I am running into is the comments section now.  I get the JSON file from reddit and then turn it into a GSON object and the problem you start to run into is with the replies.  So a comment can have replies, which is a list of more comments and those comments can have replies and so on.  When trying to display this in android it becomes confusing.  So what I have done is made a xml object that has a listview inside of it as well as the the textviews for author and the comment itself above this listview.  Now in my custom adapter it can tell if the replies has a list of objects and update that listview otherwise it hides the listview.  I know you are not supposed to put a listview inside anysort of scrollable view but how else am I supposed to handle this.  It almost works the way I am doing it but the problem is the listviews are scrollable inside each other sometimes and so what I am asking is how to make the inner Listviews wrap content or atleast act like they do.

**NEW PROBLEM**

After Doing some research I am seeing that the only way I can make my app work the way I want to is to ditch the listviews and move onto LinearLayouts.  I am trying to recursively load linear layouts within linear layouts.  What I need help with is writing the recursive method that creates the new linear layout inside parent's Linear Layout.  I will attach the code I have so far this time.

Here is what I have so far for java code for creating this recursive linear layout comment section for my practice reddit app.

```
public class CommentsFragment extends Fragment {


public CommentsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comments, container, false);
    List<Comments.ChildData> list = MainActivity.comments.getData().getChildren();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayoutComments);

    recursiveLinearLayoutCreator(list, layout);

    return view;
}

public void recursiveLinearLayoutCreator(List<Comments.ChildData> list, LinearLayout layout){
    for ( Comments.ChildData c : list) {
        boolean temp = false;
        try {
            temp = ( c.getData().getReplies().getData() != null );
        } catch ( Exception e) { temp = false; }
        if ( temp )
        {
            // need to add children to layout here after creating new layout I think`enter code here`
            recursiveLinearLayoutCreator( c.getData().getReplies().getData().getChildren(), // need to put current layout in);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my Linear Layout Item for the comments that will have their children added to their linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/commentTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="comment" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/authorTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="author" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/CommentLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my top level Linear Layout, the one that I start with than add recursively too

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context="com.example.ejf011.scroller.CommentsFragment"
android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayoutComments">


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, back with the solution.  Here is the code for the CommentsFragment which handles recursively looking through my list of GSON objects to create recursive Linear Layouts to handle reddit comments.

```
public class CommentsFragment extends Fragment {

public LayoutInflater mInflater;
public ViewGroup mContainer;


public CommentsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comments, container, false);
    mInflater = inflater;
    mContainer = container;
    List<Comments.ChildData> list = MainActivity.comments.getData().getChildren();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayoutComments);
    recursiveLinearLayoutCreator(list, layout);
    return view;
}

public void recursiveLinearLayoutCreator(List<Comments.ChildData> list, LinearLayout layout){
    for ( Comments.ChildData c : list) {
        boolean temp;
        try {
            temp = ( c.getData().getReplies().getData() != null );
            c.getData().getBody();
            c.getData().getAuthor();
        } catch ( Exception e) { temp = false; }
        if ( temp )
        {
            LinearLayout newLayout = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_item, layout, false);
            Log.d("child being made", c.getData().getBody());
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(newLayout);
            holder.comment.setText(c.getData().getBody());
            holder.author.setText(c.getData().getAuthor());
            layout.addView(newLayout);
            recursiveLinearLayoutCreator(c.getData().getReplies().getData().getChildren(), holder.ll);
        }

    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView comment;
    TextView author;
    LinearLayout ll;

    ViewHolder(View view){
        comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentTextView);
        author = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.authorTextView);
        ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.CommentLinearLayout);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Fragment that sort of acts as a root fragment.  It is a linearlayout with a scroll view with a linear layout inside it.  Will Clean up later.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context="com.example.ejf011.scroller.CommentsFragment"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollCommentsVertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayoutComments"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And Finally my post_item.xml which is the item I fill the linear layouts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:weightSum="100">

<Space
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/PostThumbnailImageView"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="56"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleOfThePost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title of the Post" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AuthorOfThePost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Author of the Post" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PostSubReddit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="r/random" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Bonus**

GSON class for comments retrieved from json file for a posts comments

```
public class Comments {
private String kind;
private CommentChildData data;

public String getKind() {
    return kind;
}

public void setKind(String kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
}

public CommentChildData getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(CommentChildData data) {
    this.data = data;
}

static public class CommentChildData {
    private String modhash;
    private List<ChildData> children;
    private String before;
    private String after;

    public String getModhash() {
        return modhash;
    }

    public void setModhash(String modhash) {
        this.modhash = modhash;
    }

    public List<ChildData> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<ChildData> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getBefore() {
        return before;
    }

    public void setBefore(String before) {
        this.before = before;
    }

    public String getAfter() {
        return after;
    }

    public void setAfter(String after) {
        this.after = after;
    }
}

static public class ChildData {
    private String kind;
    private CommentData data;

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public CommentData getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(CommentData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

static public class CommentData {
    private String subredd_id;
    private String banned_by;
    private String removal_reason;
    private String link_id;
    private String likes;
    private Comments replies;
    private Object user_reports;
    private Boolean saved;
    private boolean id;
    private int gilded;
    private String report_reason;
    private String author;
    private String parent_id;
    private int score;
    private String approved_by;
    private int controversiality;
    private String body;
    private String edited;
    private String author_flair_css_class;
    private int downs;
    private String body_html;
    private String subreddit;
    private boolean score_hidden;
    private String name;
    private int created;
    private String author_flair_text;
    private int created_utc;
    private String distinguished;
    private Object mod_reports;
    private String num_reports;
    private int ups;

    public String getSubredd_id() {
        return subredd_id;
    }

    public void setSubredd_id(String subredd_id) {
        this.subredd_id = subredd_id;
    }

    public String getBanned_by() {
        return banned_by;
    }

    public void setBanned_by(String banned_by) {
        this.banned_by = banned_by;
    }

    public String getRemoval_reason() {
        return removal_reason;
    }

    public void setRemoval_reason(String removal_reason) {
        this.removal_reason = removal_reason;
    }

    public String getLink_id() {
        return link_id;
    }

    public void setLink_id(String link_id) {
        this.link_id = link_id;
    }

    public String getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(String likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public Comments getReplies() {
        return replies;
    }

    public void setReplies(Comments replies) {
        this.replies = replies;
    }

    public Object getUser_reports() {
        return user_reports;
    }

    public void setUser_reports(Object user_reports) {
        this.user_reports = user_reports;
    }

    public Boolean getSaved() {
        return saved;
    }

    public void setSaved(Boolean saved) {
        this.saved = saved;
    }

    public boolean isId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(boolean id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getGilded() {
        return gilded;
    }

    public void setGilded(int gilded) {
        this.gilded = gilded;
    }

    public String getReport_reason() {
        return report_reason;
    }

    public void setReport_reason(String report_reason) {
        this.report_reason = report_reason;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getParent_id() {
        return parent_id;
    }

    public void setParent_id(String parent_id) {
        this.parent_id = parent_id;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getApproved_by() {
        return approved_by;
    }

    public void setApproved_by(String approved_by) {
        this.approved_by = approved_by;
    }

    public int getControversiality() {
        return controversiality;
    }

    public void setControversiality(int controversiality) {
        this.controversiality = controversiality;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getEdited() {
        return edited;
    }

    public void setEdited(String edited) {
        this.edited = edited;
    }

    public String getAuthor_flair_css_class() {
        return author_flair_css_class;
    }

    public void setAuthor_flair_css_class(String author_flair_css_class) {
        this.author_flair_css_class = author_flair_css_class;
    }

    public int getDowns() {
        return downs;
    }

    public void setDowns(int downs) {
        this.downs = downs;
    }

    public String getBody_html() {
        return body_html;
    }

    public void setBody_html(String body_html) {
        this.body_html = body_html;
    }

    public String getSubreddit() {
        return subreddit;
    }

    public void setSubreddit(String subreddit) {
        this.subreddit = subreddit;
    }

    public boolean isScore_hidden() {
        return score_hidden;
    }

    public void setScore_hidden(boolean score_hidden) {
        this.score_hidden = score_hidden;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(int created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getAuthor_flair_text() {
        return author_flair_text;
    }

    public void setAuthor_flair_text(String author_flair_text) {
        this.author_flair_text = author_flair_text;
    }

    public int getCreated_utc() {
        return created_utc;
    }

    public void setCreated_utc(int created_utc) {
        this.created_utc = created_utc;
    }

    public String getDistinguished() {
        return distinguished;
    }

    public void setDistinguished(String distinguished) {
        this.distinguished = distinguished;
    }

    public Object getMod_reports() {
        return mod_reports;
    }

    public void setMod_reports(Object mod_reports) {
        this.mod_reports = mod_reports;
    }

    public String getNum_reports() {
        return num_reports;
    }

    public void setNum_reports(String num_reports) {
        this.num_reports = num_reports;
    }

    public int getUps() {
        return ups;
    }

    public void setUps(int ups) {
        this.ups = ups;
    }
}
}
```